# Datatable in Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

While do databinding , in JSF we have  datatable feature for arranging data in a table with style.

Is there any feature like datatable in spring MVC ? I do it using JSTL forEach as normally.
But if there any feature like datatable(in JSF) , we can easly manage it including their CSS style.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing specific to Spring MVC - it doesn't really provide any UI components see [Spring MVC & UI Components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7520490/spring-mvc-ui-components)

In the past I've ended up using either JSP tag libraries or JavaScript libraries.

You might want to look at [Display Tag](http://www.displaytag.org/1.2/) (JSP) or [jQuery Datatables plugin](http://www.datatables.net/) (JavaScript). With Display Tag I've often ended up writing some utility classes for abstracting out & handling the paging/sorting in a controller.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend the **[datatables4j](http://datatables4j.github.com/docs/index.html)** (based on [jQuery DataTables](http://datatables.net/)), it works pretty well with Spring MVC.

See also

- https://github.com/datatables4j
- [Integrating Spring MVC with jQuery, Bootstrap, DataTables4J and webjars](https://speakerdeck.com/michaelisvy/integrating-spring-mvc-with-jquery-bootstrap-datatables4j-and-webjars)

Comment: Absolutely ! :-) And DataTables4j provides also a Thymeleaf support if needed !

Comment: Datatables4j was renamed to Dandelion Datatables. http://dandelion.github.io/datatables/

Comment: All link is 404 now.

Answer (score 0):

I have integrated Spring MVC, Hibernate and DataTables in several projects. I have written a [howto specific for Spring Roo](http://www.pabloguerrero.org/cgblog/2/15/DataTables-server-side-processing-integration-with-Spring-Roo-and-Hibernate) but it can be easily applied to a normal Spring MVC application and with any JPA implementation.

There is also a [link to the whole project in github](https://github.com/yellowtrolley/RooDataTablesHibernate).